# Unable to pull remote Openfiles.exe data into PHP

Tags: php, windows, apache, shell-exec

I'm trying to use openfiles.exe to grab the information of what files are currently open on a remote server. I can run the command from the command prompt that the webserver is on, so I know that it works between the webserver and the server I'm trying to target. However, when I try to call the same command in PHP, I get an Apache Error Log Entry of: "ERROR: The Target system must be running Windows XP or above." The webserver is running on Xp Pro, and the target server is on Windows Server 2003. From a command prompt the command runs flawlessly, even to older Windows 2000 servers on the network, it's just when I run it from PHP that it appears to have a problem. Does anyone have any ideas as to why and/or how to get around this?

The code that I'm using is:

```
$output = shell_exec("openfiles /query /s servername");
echo $output;
  $i = 0;
  $c = count($output);

  while ($i < $c) {
    $dump = $output[$i];
    echo $dump ."<br>";
    $i++;
  }
```

shell_exec(), system() and exec() all behave exactly the same, as does running the command from a batch file. A slightly interesting turn is that if I drop the "/s servername" part, it does output the following:

```
Files Opened Remotely via local share points:
---------------------------------------------
INFO: No shared open files found.
```

... so it's as if the /s flag is what's throwing it. Like I say, it works fine from command prompt, so I know that the executable is capable of pulling the information from the target server; I just need to find out why PHP seems to have a problem with doing the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Apache server is running under the wrong account, and doesn't have permissions to the remote IPC$ shares ;)

edit - full post:

Could be permissions? What user does Apache run as? When you do it from a command prompt, you're presumably doing it as a domain admin account, or other account which would have the correct permissions to connect to the IPC$ share on the remote computer (IIRC that's how stuff like this is done). Whereas Apache may not, and it could be just a misleading error message when what's actually happening is that it can't contact the IPC$ share and assumes from that that the remote computer doesn't' have Windows XP or above...

Looks like on the XP version of openfiles, there's /u and /p options to pass a username and password; stick domain admin credentials in there to test, and see if that works. If it does, create a restricted AD account with no filestore permissions and use those credentials or something, to make sure no one can steal your main domain admin account.

Comment: That's done it, you genius!! Unfortunately I can't give you any rep, but thanks!

Comment: Ah, now I can - all is well in the world :D